# Chips change color on hover

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using a chip on my code and I want to change the color when mouse it's over it. I tryed using

```
hover:{
            backgroundColor: 'red',
        }
```

I used `const StyledChip = withStyles( ...`

But it's not working! Can someone help me? Thanks in advice!

The code is something like

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Avatar from '@material-ui/core/Avatar';
import Chip from '@material-ui/core/Chip';

const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
  },
  chip: {
    margin: theme.spacing.unit,
  },
});

const StyledChip = withStyles({
  root: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
  '&:hover': {
    backgroundColor: 'red',
  }
})(Chip);


function Chips(props) {
  const { classes } = props;
  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>

      <StyledChip
        avatar={
          <Avatar>
            <FaceIcon />
          </Avatar>
        }
        label="Clickable Deletable Chip"
      />
    </div>
  );
}

Chips.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(Chips);
```

I tryed to fix it in a different way but does not work

Comment: Could you make an minimal working example of what you tried here: https://codesandbox.io/ ?

Comment: Please see [ask] and edit your question to include a [mcve]

Comment: Just updated the question @mathiasfk

Answer (score 1):

The first level of keys in the object passed to `withStyles` are just the keys that you can use (in the `classes` prop passed to the component) to get at the actual CSS class names generated by `withStyles`.

So when you have the following:

```
const StyledChip = withStyles({
  root: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
  '&:hover': {
    backgroundColor: 'red',
  }
})(Chip);
```

this means that `Chip` would have access to two different classes -- one via `props.classes.root` that has the effect of setting the background to white, and one via `props.classes['&:hover']` that has the effect of setting the background to red. The `Chip` component isn't going to look at that second class at all so it has no effect.

However, if you use the following syntax:

```
const StyledChip = withStyles({
  root: {
    backgroundColor: "white",
    "&:hover": {
      backgroundColor: "red"
    }
  }
})(Chip);
```

the "&:hover" is now **part** of the `root` class definition. Now the `&` means "the class that this key is part of" and therefore will generate CSS like the following:

```
.root-generated-class-name {
  background-color: white;
}
.root-generated-class-name:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

In this example `props.classes.root` would have a value of `root-generated-class-name`.

Here's a working example:

[image: Edit o8vvlzn2z]